# Sql queries in VBA code - how to comment after Sql string

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have some Sql queries inside VBA code, this is an example of a line of code:

```
strQry = strQry & Worksheets("Data").Cells(9, 7) & """, " & _
```

I need to add a comment **at the end of this line**. Like this:

```
strQry = strQry & Worksheets("Data").Cells(9, 7) & """, " & _ 'comment hjjkk
```

I usually comment using an apostrophe but the character is not accepted on that line. Please advise. Also, I need the comment on that exact line if possible, at the end of it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `& _` it means you got code on the next line and that instruction is not finished.
So if you type a comment right after `& _` it's like if your inserting a comment in the middle of your instruction

For example:

```
   myVar = 3 + 5 & _ 'comment at the wrong place
          +2

   =

   myVar = 3 +5 'comment at the wrong place + 2
```

So all you can do is

```
myVar = 3 + 5 'comment
myVar = myvar + 2
```

or in your case it would look like this

```
strQry = strQry & Worksheets("Data").Cells(9, 7) & """, " 'Comment
strQry = styQry &...
```

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with the SQL query itself, you are trying to add a comment after a line continuation, which is not allowed.

From the [MSDN documentation on comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx185bk6.aspx):

> Comments cannot follow a line-continuation sequence on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

with the line break `_`  you cannot comment on that line as for VB the line doesn't stop yet (it is a feature to improve readability for us programmers). Get accustomed to comment before or after the complete string

Alternatively you can build the string up in parts and after each part you can add comments:

```
strQry = strQry & Worksheets("Data").Cells(9, 7) 'comment 1

strQry = strQry & ", " & <next part> 'comment2
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

The underscore at the end of the line signifies to VB that the code continues on the next line. You can't put anything after the underscore. If you need a comment at the end of the line, you will need to restructure your code to end that line, put your comment and continue your string concatenation on the next line.